# Webapp in iOS opens popup when outside scope

Tags: ios, mobile, web-applications, scope, manifest

Since Apple iOS 13.1+ all webapps without the proper manifest and/or scope directive will be left with a **popup** IN the webapp when changing URL's. When the manifest is OK and holds the right scope (e.g. "/") all navigates like before. The problem is when my clients want to pay on my website and they are redirected to my payment provider. This URL change (also domain change) is again opened IN this popup instead in a flow from my shop. 
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

After long search i found the way of loading the manifest was the problem. We added this in correct (and checked) syntax in the head segment of the HTML. However we used the JSON type inclusion. We found that when using inline link tag, using rel="manifest", we should not put the JSON within the tags but in the href attribute like so: href="data:application/manifest+json,{}"/>. The same JSON output goes between the acculade brackets and then the scope and starturl are processed by the browsers.